# Error after AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I have made several of these files all duplicates of one another with just destination, trigger and of course variables changed so they do not interact with each other the others work perfect and post the data without any problem but this one is giving me problems I have searched google more than once and I just can't find a solution so I hope that someone can help me here.

What is happening:
when I click the save button it triggers the jquery to preform an ajax post to a php file.  The php error log says that it is an undefined index:

> [Tue Jan 15 18:39:25 2013] [error] [client] PHP Notice: Undefined index: edit_username in

**the jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#hk_save').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData3 = $('#master_lid').serialize();
        submitdata(formData3);

    });
}); 



function submitdata(formData3) {

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'inc/system/save_lid.php',     
        data: formData3,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async:false,
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function(data) {           

            alert(data.msg);

        }
    }); 
};
```

**the php**

```
include("./global2.php");
$error_message  = "";

//Sanitize incoming data and store in variable
$username       = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['edit_username'])));
$mail       = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['edit_mail'])));


if(!empty($username))
{

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET mail = '".$mail."'WHERE username = '".$username."' ");

$result ='Gebruiker "'.$username.'" is met success gewijzigd.';
}
else
{
    $result = "Ow nee!, er heeft zich een error voorgedaan!";
}

            $return['msg'] = $result; 
            echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
```

and yes I have checked the fields for spelling errors and such and know they are correct.

Comment: So it actually POST's but the PHP is having errors?  You should more careful in how you explain your problem because "won't POST" to many will mean the client never performs the POST action at all. Can you be specific about what the error message is?

Comment: it doesn't do the post action, the php is fine, used it in my other files the same way and no problem at all.

Comment: FYI: It impossible to have a timeout with a synchronous XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Then why the comment about the PHP error log if the POST doesn;t actually take place?  If the POSt doesn't take place, your server would not even record a request at all.

Comment: as i said it says the varible does not excist witch is filled by the post action, the jquery gives a post to the php and it gives back a repondse (the alert) it give the error alert ($result = "Ow nee!, er heeft zich een error voorgedaan!") back so its not a time out

Comment: Did you console and see what is in formData3? Have you inspected the Ajax request to see what is sent to the server? What is `master_lid`?

Comment: oh and as you can read within the code the error message is made if the varible $username (which is filled by the request) is empty, so it does not preform as it should

Comment: @JDewzy serialize will actually work on anything that contains form elements.

Comment: @JDewzy yes it is a form

Comment: @MikeBrant's point is that the POST is happening.  All it means when we say a POST is working is that data is getting sent to the server.  That's obviously happening, or your PHP would never attempt to run.  I'd take two steps to debug.  First, in your javascript, add a `console.log(formData3)`, and second, in your PHP, add a `var_dump($_REQUEST)`.  The exact error message from the log would be helpful as well.

Comment: @ernie thank you, the jquery does get the varibles but there is no trace of the debug in the logs.

Comment: well, this `trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(` will not protect against sql injection!!! please use mysqli_real_escape_string or PDO

Comment: this is the only error i get when the execution happen: [Tue Jan 15 18:39:25 2013] [error] [client] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: edit_username in

Comment: @Luis Siquot it's just a concept api for now, so i need to make it as quick as i can, its on a private server so i don't care much for those errors at the moment, thanks for your concern though :)

Comment: The only way to solve this is to determine why that index is undefined, which brings us back to the `console.log(formData3)` and `var_dump($_REQUEST)`.  Both will show you that you don't have an `edit_username` field, and will likely show you what is getting serialized so you can correct the data being POST'ed.  Show us the output from both these (you may want to put an exit after the var_dump, so you can see the output before the PHP errors)

Comment: @ernie only the console log shows the varibles, the var dump does not show in the logs at all.